# 400: bad request when using hashlib on flask login

Tags: python, html, hash, flask, flask-login

I'm setting up some basic database hashing, but upon setup I'm receiving a 400 bad request.

This is my first time using hashes and I could use some advice. I don't plan on salting the hashes.
is there something I'm missing on the HTML side?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template, Markup, request, redirect, session, flash, url_for, flash, g
from flask_login import LoginManager,login_manager, current_user, login_required, login_user, logout_user, UserMixin, confirm_login, fresh_login_required
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from functools import wraps
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms import StringField
from socket import *            #required for sock address issue.
import mraa
from OpenSSL import SSL
import sys
import form
import time
import sqlite3
import hashlib
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)     #removing breaks everything.
@app.errorhandler(404)                         #  handles important errors    
                                               #   ^
def errorpage(e):                              #   ^      
    return render_template('404.html')         #   ^          \[T]/
@app.errorhandler(500)                         #   ^           |@| 
def errorpage500(e):                           #   ^           / \
    flash('error 500')                         #   ^     Praise the ASCII
                                               #       
def login_required(f):                         # makes login required modifier work                     
    @wraps(f)                                  #     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):                 #     @the only reason people keep using@
        if 'logged_in' in session:             #     @vi is they cant figure out how to@ 
            return f(*args, **kwargs)          #     @exit it.                         @
        else:                                  #     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                          
            flash('please login first.')       ##                         
            return redirect (url_for('index')) ################################                                  
    return wrap                                                          




def getHash(passText):
    hashPass=hashlib.sha512()
    hashPass.update(passtext)
    return(hashPass.hexdigest())


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    db = sqlite3.connect('sql.sql3')
    db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    epass=getHash(request.form['postPass'])
    query="select username, password from users where username=? and password=?"
    t=(request.form['postUser'], epass)
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query,t)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(rows) ==1:
        bodyText=request.form['postUser'] + " " + request.form["postPass"]
        bodyText=bodyText + "Success!"
        session['authenticated']='yes'
    else:
        bodyText = "incorrect login."   
    return render_template('/index.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

here's a copy of the traceback but I'm not sure what this means.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py:7: UserWarning: Module _functools was already imported from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so, but /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py:7: UserWarning: Module functools was already imported from /usr/lib/python2.7/functools.pyc, but /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloflask.py", line 69, in <module>
    app.logger.info(request.form)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

[Here's the requested debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrhrB.jpg)

Comment: Aside: You say "I don't plan on salting the hashes." You are clearly aware of salting; why on earth would you choose not to do it?

Comment: What does the traceback say? Your `getHash()` function appears to have a typo in it: Your parameter is called `passText`, but inside the function you use `passtext`.

Comment: this is for school and just enough trouble as it is. I've been awake for 27 hours already. I just want to get this done. I still have to implement sensors and the confirmation email.

Comment: Chris, I fixed the typo and no change, not getting a traceback. only serving flask app "html.helloflask" my python script is helloflask.py and the html is index.html

Comment: You need to narrow this down… we're not here to figure out what's wrong with your code. Are you saying the _only_ error message you are seeing is "400: Bad Request"? Do you have debug mode enabled?

Comment: yes I do, I'll add a screenshot of the .log I set up. unfortunately it looks to be next to useless...

Comment: added the sql.py just in case something there could possibly be causing the issue.

Comment: @Zane - how are you running the app? Do you have a run_app.py, or similar. Your log would indicate that `/` is not being found when the app is initialised

Comment: "export FLASK_APP=helloflask.py" then "flask run --host='0.0.0.0' " Its running on yocto linux if that matters.

Comment: @jprockbelly is there another way I should be running it?

Comment: @Zane - the 400 error tells us that is can't find the `@app.route('/')` view. I can't see how this will be an issue with the HTML or the database connection. Do you have `app = Flask(__name__)` somewhere in the set up? What is in `helloflask.py`

Comment: @jprockbelly yes, I've updated with the full helloflask.py

Comment: @jprockbelly would '__init__.py' be relevant?

Comment: @Zane - sorry I can't run this at the moment, will need to get on my other PC. Only thing I can see is the port from the log is 5000, but you have 443 in your script?

Comment: @jprockbelly this could be relevant now that I look at it. it doesn't look like that part of the code is working, but if that was the issue, 192.168.1.195:5000/signup wouldn't be working either, right? as long as my professor is convinced I'm using https I'm not too worried about that code.

Comment: moved form to post. issue still occurs.

Comment: @Zane - thanks for posting the traceback. The offending line `app.logger.info(request.form)` isn't actually in the example you provided, so hard to know for sure, but editted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.form['postPass']`

This is not populated on GET request only POST so that will be an issue.

If you want both GET and POST in this view I suggest doing this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #process the posted data
        return something

    if request.method == 'GET':
        #do something else
        return something_else
```

Also your traceback tells you that this is an issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloflask.py", line 69, in <module>
    app.logger.info(request.form)

...

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

On line 69 you are trying to log a `request` object that only exists in the context of a request from a user. Start by commenting this line out

Comment: No such luck. it doesn't even seem like that section is working. port 443 just gives 'page cannot be displayed' and no error code whatsoever. at least port 5000 is giving error 400. my other html files work with the / in front of them but I tried it anyways. No change.

Comment: referring to your sneaky edit, it looks like that line is from where I put in the code recommended to me for the traceback. i'll link the forum it was suggested to me [here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/676ah0/400_bad_request_when_using_hashlib_on_flask_login/dgo5x7s/) What should I do specifically about request.form['postPass']?

Comment: @Zane - `if request.method == 'POST':` do the post stuff. `if request.method == 'GET':` do the get stuff

Comment: I might be showing my inner noob here, but I'm still not understanding what you mean. I get the difference between get and post, but I'm unsure what part of the code you are referencing

Comment: @Zane - inside your `def index():` you need to check if you are handelling a GET or a POST request. If it's GET you won't have anything in `request.form` so you can't call it. See my edit above

Comment: that is defined under the <form method=""> correct? edit: I've been awake way too long. sorry.

Comment: my goal here is to pull from the sqlite table to check and make sure the username and password are authenticated. for use in index.html to act as a sign in page. What am I messing up? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Zane - replace your index function with [this](https://gist.github.com/jsharples/9d83234e04109c895602677ce8e2ca1b). If that doesn't work go to bed and get some sleep.

Comment: I'll try it shortly and Mark it resolved. Thanks for all the help.